# How do I see more rivals' best time in Super Mario 3D Land?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I notice that in each level my time is being compared to a rival. I want to know who my rivals are, and if I'm the fastest one in the world in completing that level. Is that possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm - I haven't noticed this in the game.  Does it happen for StreetPass friends or only friend-listed friends?

Comment: I think those avatars are my StreetPass friends. I also only got this after finishing the game and the Bonus worlds I think.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know it will only show the face of the rival for that particular level. the game itself does not have any official place to track world wide records.

even though you can see from the numbers the one that has the best time is in gold and is shown first when you stand on that level spot on the overworld map.

I looked around for any record keeping on websites and TMK seems to have one which also requires proof of accomplishment. http://www.themushroomkingdom.net/records/sm3dl

there is also others but they are more like forum threads and don't require proof so they aren't as reliable.